# Using objects instead of arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I've spent nearly 1 week to learn working with objects instead of arrays. I had thought it was easy to call them and created some objects and set their properties. However I can't access them now, I tried this:

```
function onBoxClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var str:String = event.currentTarget.name;
    trace(str);
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
    trace(getChildByName("copy_" + str)); // trying to trace an object by name
}
```

My question is if there's a practical way of dealing with objects, otherwise what's the purpose of using them.
Edit: Here's my function that I use to create movieclips and other things:

```
function addBoxes(isUpdate:Boolean):void {
    var copyOne:Object = getReadOnlyValues();
    copyOne.name = "copy_" + num;

    // Set default mc1 settings
    var settings1:Object = copyOne.mc1Settings;
    for(var num2:String in settings1) {
        copyOne.mc1[num2] = settings1[num2];
    }

    // Set default mc1text settings
    var settings2:Object = copyOne.mc1TextSettings;
    for(var num3:String in settings2) {
        copyOne.mc1Text[num3] = settings2[num3];
    }

    copyOne.mc1.x = nextXpos;
    copyOne.mc1.name = "captionBox_" + num;

    addChild(copyOne.mc1);
    copyOne.mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCaptionClick);

    copyOne.mc1Text.name = "captionBoxText_" + num;
    copyOne.mc1.addChild(copyOne.mc1Text);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------  
    // Set default mc2 settings
    var settings4:Object = copyOne.mc2Settings;
    for(var num4:String in settings4) {
        copyOne.mc2[num4] = settings4[num4];
    }

    // Set default mc2text settings
    var settings5:Object = copyOne.mc2TextSettings;
    for(var num5:String in settings5) {
        copyOne.mc2Text[num5] = settings5[num5];
    }

    copyOne.mc2.x = nextXpos;
    copyOne.mc2.y = copyOne.mc1.height;
    copyOne.mc2.name = "box2_" + num;

    addChild(copyOne.mc2);

    copyOne.mc2Text.name = "box2BoxText_" + num;
    copyOne.mc2.addChild(copyOne.mc2Text);

    copyOne.mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBoxClick);

    if (num / subunits is int) {
        trace (num);

        // createMc("normalBox", true);
    }

    nextXpos = nextXpos + copyOne.mc2.width;

    // traceObj(copyOne);
    // traceObj(getReadOnlyValues());
}
```

I called this function in a loop so I created many movieclips. Now I can't access objects' properties and their childen (e.g textfield).

Objects I have on stage: Movieclips and textfields

Where they come from: The function above

What I'm trying to do with them: Tracing movieclips and textfields (that are holded by objects) to change their children (textfield) text

What happens instead of what I expect: Trace code outputs undefined instead of giving me object type `trace(getChildByName("copy_" + str)); // trying to trace an object by name`

Is there a practical way of accessing an object whose name is "copy_1" and its property whose name is "box2_1" (movieclip)?

Comment: The question is too general and sort of philosophic. Please try to rephrase, what exactly is not working for you in that piece of code? What do you expect out of it and what are you getting instead?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited the question. (sort of philosophic :) )

Comment: I'm not sure how this question relates to objects/arrays vs. event listeners for accessing Display Objects. From your code it looks like you are trying to access a portion of string to get a MovieClip or something but the disconnect for me is "I've spent nearly 1 week to learn working with objects instead of arrays."

Comment: Yeah, still not very clear as to what you're trying to do.
The way of accessing objects is by using references to their instances. For example if you go do `var myMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();`, you then can access the object my the reference `myMC`. But I'm pretty sure that's not your issue.
Try to describe what objects you have on stage, where they came from, what you're trying to do with them and what happens instead of what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I edited the question again. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I give up. I'll use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is the "copyOne" object has been created within the scope of "addBoxes", so it will no longer exist outside of this function.

Another is you're trying to access an Object via getChildByName, which only addresses displayObjects of the displayObjectContainer you are calling from.

If you want to loosely keep track of variables with things like Objects or MovieClips (which are both dynamic-style objects that let you add properties to them as you wish), just use MovieClips to house your values. The movieClips, being on the stage, will be retained in memory until removed from the displayList (stage).

Also, check out the Dictionary, a sort of key/value based way of storing collections of objects.

Better yet, if you use strongly-typed custom objects (creating your own classes to extend MCs, and adding your own public or private methods and values), there are benefits such as using Vectors (fancy, fast arrays that are compatible with any Object type you choose).

Comment: thank you for your answer. so I need to impove my coding, learning to use custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I understood your question or not, but as @ozmachine said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072550/using-objects-instead-of-arrays/28074135#28074135), you can not use [`getChildByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29), instead I think that you can take a look on this, may be it can help :

```
var container:DisplayObjectContainer = this;

function getReadOnlyValues():Object {
    return {
        mc1: new box(),
        mc1: {
            name: 'mc1_',
            alpha: 1,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 30,
            height: 25
        },
        mc1Text: new TextField(),
        mc1Text: {
            text: 'test',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            selectable: false,
            multiline: false,
            wordWrap: false
        }
    }
};

// create 5 objects
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){

    container['copy_'+i] = getReadOnlyValues();

    var obj:Object = getObjectByName('copy_'+i);
        obj.mc1.alpha = 1;
        obj.mc1.x = 0;
        obj.mc1.y = 50 * i;
        obj.mc1.width = 100;   

        obj.mc1.addChild(obj.mc1Text);
        obj.mc1Text.text = 'test_' + i;

    addChild(obj.mc1);
}
// get object by name
function getObjectByName(name:String):Object {
    return container[name];
}

// change the text of the 4th button
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    var obj:Object = getObjectByName('copy_3');
        obj.mc1Text.text = 'new text';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Array and Object are both data structures.
Data means some form of information.
Data structure means some form of information being stored in a certain way.

**Array and Object are two different ways to store information.**

Arrays identify data with integer numbers.
An integer number to identify a single element of an array is called an **index**

**Arrays are ideal to represent a list of similar things that belong to each other.**

```
var names:Array = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"];
```

This often means that the elements of an array are of the same type, like in the example above.
But they don't have to:

```
var numbers:Array = [42, "twenty-five", "XIIV"];
```

For the above examples it's easy to answer the questions "What are the names of the  four beatles?", "What different representations of numbers did you stumble upon during your trip through the historic town?". Other questions are harder or impossible to answer. "What Roman numerals did you stumble upon in the historic town?"

Objects identify data with names.
A name to identify a single element of an object is called a **property**

**Objects are ideal to represent a list of dissimilar things that belong to each other.**

```
var paula:Object = {age:37, name:"Paula", hairColor:0x123456};
```

This often means that the elements of an object are of different type, like in the example above.
But they don't have to:

```
var car:Object = {manufacturer:"Porsche", color:"red", sound:"wroooooom", soundOfDriver:"weeeeeeeeeeee"};
```

Considering this, let's take a look at your code and see how it applies.
The big picture is that you have a function `addBoxes` that you call multiple times. As one function should have one purpose, **this function will do something similar** every time it is executed. Uh-Oh: "similar". Whatever the result of this function is, it should go into an array. Each call to that function would be an element of the array. You can see this clearly on your use of "num" to identify whatever is happening in your current run of the function.

**What data is present in your function?**

- copyOne
- mc1
- mc1Text
- mc2
- mc2Text

copyOne is a troublemaker here and what causes your confusion. It's trying to do everything at once and therefore you are not able to think clearly about when to use a Array and when Object. One would call it a god object. And that's not a good object to have around.

Your choice for variable names is very bad.
You choose super generic names like "mcX" only to later add a name property to it that describes what it truly is.
But even that doesn't hold true for whatever "Box2" is supposed to be.
**Choose names so that it'S easy to understand what something in your code is.**
It looks like you created all or parts of this structure jsut for this question and therefore lacked meaningful names.
**I highly recommend that you do not learn by such made up projects. But from the real world.**

I will therefore impose the following goal:
mc1 and mc1Text represent a caption
mc2 and mc2Text represent a content

With all this, I ask again:

**What data is present in your function?**

- captionBox
- captionText
- contentBox
- contentText

Both caption and content consist of a box and a text.
These are different things, so caption and content are each an object with properties "box" and "text"
One could think that due to this similarity, they both should go into an array.
But I beg to differ. A caption and a text are not the same thing. You deal with captions and texts differently. Walking on the streets you might catch a big caption in the news quickly, but not a lengthy text. That's why each of them should be a property of the object that's created in the function.

Here's somewhat of a **conclusion**:

```
var allBoxes:Array = [];  // array to store the similar results of every function call

function createBoxes():void 
{
    var boxes:Object = {};

    //the box consists of caption & content, both bying of the same type, but are containing different data

    boxes.caption = {box:{}, text:{}}; //caption
    boxes.content = {box:{}, text:{}}; //content

    allBoxes.push(boxes);
}
```

This is it. That's how and why I would model your data with objects and arrays.

But it doesn't end here. My conclusion lacks a lot of the code you posted.
While the above is mostly language independent, the missing code is specific to Actionscript and not just on how to model data. It's as follows...

As3 is object oriented.
This is good, because the above conclusion has a lot of objects in it.
To define how some object is/does/moves/farts/etc, one creates classes.

The following changes take place (for reasons out of the scope of this answer):

- `createBoxes` (formerly known as addBoxes) calls the constructor of
  a class "CaptionAndContent" that extends Sprite.
- There's no more need to explicitely create an object "boxes" as the constructor does exactly that.
- The `caption` and `content` will not have a property "box", because
  they can be the box themselves. This is exactly how it's done in the
  code of the question. The default settings are set in the constructors of their classes.

Here's reduced snippet of code that hopefully illustrates how the classes ***could*** look like.
Each class should be in its own file, with the necessary imports, package block and the additional functionality that you did not specify in your question.

```
public class CaptionAndContent extends Sprite
{
    private var caption:Caption;
    private var content:Content;

    public function CaptionAndContent(captionText:String = "", contentText:String = "")
    {
        caption = new Caption(captionText);
        addChild(caption);

        content = new Content(contentText);
        content.y = caption.height;
        addChild(content);
    }
}

public class ClickableBoxWithText extends Sprite
{
    protected var textField:TextField;
    public function ClickableBoxWithText(text:String = "")
    {
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.text = text;
        addChild(textField);

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    protected function onClick(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //override this in a sublclass
    }
}

public class Caption extends ClickableBoxWithText
{
    public function Caption(text:String = "")
    {
        super(text);

        // apply all the default settings of caption here.
    }
}

public class Content extends ClickableBoxWithText
{
    public function Content(text:String = "")
    {
        super(text);

        // apply all the default settings of content here.
    }
}
```

Using them would look something like this:

```
var allBoxes:Array = [];  // array to store the similar results of every function call

function createBoxes():void
{
    var captionAndContent:CaptionAndContent = new CaptionAndContent("This is the caption...", "...for this content");
    captionAndContent.x = nextXpos;
    addChild(captionAndContent);

    allBoxes.push(captionAndContent);
}
```

Last but not least, **the identification problem in the click handler**.
Your question already contains the answer:

```
event.currentTarget
```

That's the reference to the object that was clicked on.
In my code it would be

```
mouseEvent.currentTarget
```

**This identifies the object already**. It's pointless to look up one of its properties (its name for example) in order to search all the objects for that name, just to identify the same object that you already had to identify (without a name) in order to get the name.

You aren't identifying the objects by name anyway. What differs between the names and what supposedly makes them unique is a number at their end. As pointed out in this answer, this is what's called an index and the thing you are trying to identify with it should go into an array. In my example codes, this is `allBoxes`.